# How to use list comphrehension to find columns common to all Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to find all the columns that are in all of 5 different Pandas dataframes. Currently I'm using code like this:

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, df3, df4]

cols = dfs[0].columns
for df in dfs[1:]:
    cols &= df.columns
```

Assuming this code is correct, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in a list comprehension, and if not, if there's a more effecient or less verbose way of getting the same result.

Comment: I recommend using intersection of sets of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to work with regular Python sets, you can pass in a lambda function that returns the intersection of two sets to the `reduce` function:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df0, df1, df2, df3, df4]  # list of pandas DataFrames
columns_in_common = reduce(  # a Python set
    lambda s1, s2: s1.intersection(s2),
    (set(df) for df in dfs)
)
```

Although I'd agree that `pd.Index.Intersection` makes more sense when you're dealing with pandas DataFrames.

Edit:

for completion's sake, here's a way to do it with an actual list comprehension - although we're **severely misusing a list comprehension** by simply relying on its "side-effect" of iterating over a sequence in a single line. I repeat: **this is not what list comprehensions are built for: they should be used for one thing and one thing only, that is build a list**.

```
result = []

_ = [
    result.append(colname) 
    if (
        colname not in result 
        and all(
            colname in df.columns 
            for df in dfs
    ) 
    else None 
    for df in dfs 
    for colname in df.columns
]
```

Here, the list `_` (the outcome of the list comprehension) is not important. What matters is that values have been appended to the `result` list, based on whether they appear in all DataFrame columns, and whether they don't already exist in the `result` list itself.

Besides being needlessly complex, the list comprehension is also slower than the set version (likely due to the triple for-loop inside it, and maybe also due to searches in Python lists being slower than Python sets). Here's a simple test case:

**Sets**

```
>>> timeit.timeit("import functools;lists=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 6]];functools.reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1.intersection(s2), (set(s) for s in lists))")
1.8992446570046013
```

**List Comprehension**

```
>>> timeit.timeit("mylist=[];lists=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 6]];[mylist.append(e) if e not in mylist and all(e in sublist for sublist in lists) else None for slist in lists for e in slist]")
6.89644429100008
```

The real answer to *why can't we simply append new column names to the same list being create in the list comprehension?* is because we don't have a reference to it - not before the list comprehension itself finishes, anyway. We need that reference to be able to create a list from a list comprehension with a logic more complex than a simple if/else statement.

**tl;dr** you can't really use list comprehensions to create new lists in-the-spot, if your list creation logic isn't a simple if/else test.

Comment: To have this answer directly address the question, is it possible or not to do this in a list comphrehension, and why is this method superior? Is it more efficient?

Comment: @k_n_c for the answer's sake, I edited my it to include a version using list comprehensions, although I would *never* recommend you to use over my initial version.

Answer (score 2):

We have reduce to handle this which can be used with [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html), pretty much like set.intersection:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(pd.Index.intersection,[i.columns for i in dfs])
```

---

Dummy example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABDE'))
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1,df2]
reduce(pd.Index.intersection,[i.columns for i in dfs])
#Index(['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: To have this answer directly address the question, is it possible or not to do this in a list comphrehension, and why is this method superior? Is it more efficient? Why is it superior to set.intersection? How is it similar/different?

Comment: @k_n_c it is designed for pandas.Index . with a builtin `ordering` component as well : -`sort=False`